# My Java program doesn't produce an audible sound when I'm typing in another application

Tags: java, javasound

I've written a fairly simple clock & timer program in Swing.  The timer appears to be working properly.  It counts down the seconds, minutes, and presumably hours (though I haven't tested that one yet) at the proper rate and when time expires, it plays a *.wav file to let you know.  The problem is that that sound isn't always audible if the program is running in the background.  I've done some testing just now, and I can hear the sound properly if I'm simply reading a web page in Firefox, but when I'm typing something, a URL for example, then the sound doesn't seem to play at all.

Is this a problem with my Java code--I just started working with sound in Java this weekend--or is it an operating system thing?  I'm using OpenJDK 11 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Here are (what I hope are) the relevant bits of code.

```java
class ClipPlayer implements LineListener {

    boolean playable;
    boolean done;
    AudioInputStream stream;
    Clip clip;

    public ClipPlayer(String fileName) {

        playable = false;
        done = false;
        stream = null;
        clip = null;
        File source = new File(fileName);
        boolean proceed = source.exists();  
        if (proceed) {
            try {
                stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(source);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                proceed = false;
            }
        }       
        if (proceed) {
            AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,format);
            try {
                clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                clip.addLineListener(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                proceed = false;
            }
        }
        playable = proceed;

    }

    public void close() {

        try {
            clip.close();
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }

    public void open() {

        if (playable) {
            try {
                clip.open(stream);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("The file cannot be played.");
        }

    }

    public void play() {

        if (playable && !done) {            
            try {
                clip.start();
                while (!done) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        } else if (!playable) {
            System.out.println("The file cannot be played.");
        } else if (done) {
            System.out.println("The player must be reset before it can be played again.");
        }

    }

    public void repeat(int n) {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            play();
            reset();
        }

    }

    public void reset() {

        done = false;
        clip.setFramePosition(0);

    }

    @Override
    public void update(LineEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            done = true;
        }
    }

}


class Timer extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
    private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60*MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
    private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR   = 60*MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE;

    private static final int HOURS   = 0;
    private static final int MINUTES = 1;
    private static final int SECONDS = 2;
    private static final int RESET   = 0;
    private static final int PAUSE   = 1;

    long       timeRemaining;
    boolean    finished;
    boolean    paused;
    JSpinner[] spinners;
    JButton[]  buttons;
    JLabel     remainderLabel;
    ClipPlayer player;

    public Timer() {

        timeRemaining = 0;
        finished = true;
        paused = true;
        player = new ClipPlayer("/example/path/file.wav");
        spinners = new JSpinner[3];
        spinners[HOURS] = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,99,1));
        spinners[MINUTES] = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,60,1));
        spinners[SECONDS] = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,60,1));
        buttons = new JButton[2];
        buttons[RESET] = new JButton("Begin");
        buttons[PAUSE] = new JButton("Pause");
        buttons[PAUSE].setEnabled(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
            buttons[i].setActionCommand("Button_" + i);
        }
        remainderLabel = new JLabel();

        // Layout code omitted for brevity

    }

    // actionPerformed method omitted for brevity

    public void initialize() {

        Object h = spinners[HOURS].getValue();
        Object m = spinners[MINUTES].getValue();
        Object s = spinners[SECONDS].getValue();
        timeRemaining = ((Integer)h)*MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR;
        timeRemaining += ((Integer)m)*MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
        timeRemaining += ((Integer)s)*MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
        if (timeRemaining > 0) {
            finished = false;
            paused = false;
            buttons[RESET].setText("Reset");
            buttons[PAUSE].setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            finished = true;
            paused = false;
        }

    }

    public void update(long dt) {

        if (!finished && !paused) {
            timeRemaining -= dt;
            if (timeRemaining > 0) {
                long hours = timeRemaining/MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR;
                long r = timeRemaining - hours*MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR;
                long minutes = r/MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
                r -= minutes*MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
                long seconds = r/MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(hours);
                sb.append(":");
                if (minutes < 10) sb.append("0");
                sb.append(minutes);
                sb.append(":");
                if (seconds < 10) sb.append("0");
                sb.append(seconds);
                remainderLabel.setText(sb.toString());
            } else {
                finished = true;
                buttons[RESET].setText("Begin");
                buttons[PAUSE].setEnabled(false);
                remainderLabel.setText("0:00:00");
                System.out.println("Time's up!");
                player.open();
                player.repeat(3);
                player.close();
            }
        }

    }

}

public class Time implements Runnable {

    JFrame frame;
    Clock  clock;
    Timer timer;

    // Constructor and main method omitted for brevity

    public void run() {

        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean running = true;
        while (running) {
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            clock.update(t1);
            timer.update(t1-t0);
            t0 = t1;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted Exception: " + ie.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }       
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

As I said, the program appears to work properly most of the time.  The issue is that the sound is not always audible when the program is running in the background.  I should note that the timer appears to count down properly even when running in the background.  When I realize that I've missed the sound and alt-tab back to the Java program, the timer shows 0:00:00, as expected.

Comment: Is the problem that it only works intermittently or does it just not work at all?

Comment: It works intermittently.  Sometimes there's sound, sometimes there isn't.

Comment: Since my answer below didn't ultimately work for you, you should consider posting your own answer below for others (and possibly yourself) to reference later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the code works intermittently coupled with the lack of thread-safety in the code in the question leads me to believe that you have a race condition. Basically, what's happening is that the thread that plays the sound isn't the thread that changes fields like `playable` and `done`. Consequently the changes that one thread makes to those fields won't be observed by the other thread. As such, I have refactored the code above to become thread-safe.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.time.Clock;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

class ClipPlayer implements LineListener {

    private final AtomicBoolean playable;
    private final AtomicBoolean done;
    private final Optional<AudioInputStream> stream;
    private final Optional<Clip> clip;

    public ClipPlayer(String fileName) {

        playable = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        done = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        File source = new File(fileName);
        boolean proceed = source.exists();
        stream = createAudioInputStream(source, proceed);
        if (stream == Optional.<AudioInputStream>empty()) {
            proceed = false;
        }
        clip = createClip(stream.get(), proceed);
        if (clip == Optional.<Clip>empty()) {
            proceed = false;
        }

        playable.set(proceed);
    }

    private Optional<Clip> createClip(AudioInputStream stream, boolean proceed) {
        if (!proceed) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,format);
        try {
            Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.addLineListener(this);
            return Optional.of(clip);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    private static Optional<AudioInputStream> createAudioInputStream(File source, boolean proceed) {
        if (!proceed) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        try {
            AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(source);
            Optional<AudioInputStream> optionalStream = Optional.ofNullable(stream);
            return optionalStream;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    public void close() {

        try {
            if (clip.isPresent()) {
                clip.get().close();
            }
            if (stream.isPresent()) {
                stream.get().close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }

    public void open() {

        if (playable.get()) {
            try {
                clip.get().open(stream.get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("The file cannot be played.");
        }

    }

    public void play() {

        if (playable.get() && !done.get()) {
            try {
                clip.start();
                while (!done.get()) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        } else if (!playable.get()) {
            System.out.println("The file cannot be played.");
        } else if (done.get()) {
            System.out.println("The player must be reset before it can be played again.");
        }

    }

    public void repeat(int n) {

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            play();
            reset();
        }

    }

    public void reset() {

        done.set(false);
        if (clip.isPresent()) {
            clip.get().setFramePosition(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void update(LineEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            done.set(true);
        }
    }

}


class Timer extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
    private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60*MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
    private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR   = 60*MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE;

    private static final int HOURS   = 0;
    private static final int MINUTES = 1;
    private static final int SECONDS = 2;
    private static final int RESET   = 0;
    private static final int PAUSE   = 1;

    private final AtomicLong    timeRemaining;
    private final AtomicBoolean finished;
    private final AtomicBoolean paused;
    private final JSpinner[]    spinners;
    private final JButton[]     buttons;
    private final JLabel        remainderLabel;
    private final ClipPlayer    player;

    public Timer() {

        this.timeRemaining = new AtomicLong(0L);
        this.finished = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        paused = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        player = new ClipPlayer("/example/path/file.wav");
        spinners = new JSpinner[3];
        spinners[HOURS] = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,99,1));
        spinners[MINUTES] = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,60,1));
        spinners[SECONDS] = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,60,1));
        buttons = new JButton[2];
        buttons[RESET] = new JButton("Begin");
        buttons[PAUSE] = new JButton("Pause");
        buttons[PAUSE].setEnabled(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
            buttons[i].setActionCommand("Button_" + i);
        }
        remainderLabel = new JLabel();

        // Layout code omitted for brevity

    }

    // actionPerformed method omitted for brevity

    public void initialize() {

        Object h = spinners[HOURS].getValue();
        Object m = spinners[MINUTES].getValue();
        Object s = spinners[SECONDS].getValue();
        timeRemaining.set(((Integer)h)*MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR);
        timeRemaining.addAndGet(((Integer)m)*MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE);
        timeRemaining.addAndGet(((Integer)s)*MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND);
        if (timeRemaining.get() > 0) {
            this.finished.set(false);
            paused.set(false);
            buttons[RESET].setText("Reset");
            buttons[PAUSE].setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            this.finished.set(true);
            paused.set(false);
        }

    }

    public void update(long dt) {

        if (!finished.get() && !paused.get()) {
            timeRemaining.addAndGet(-1 * dt);
            if (timeRemaining.get() > 0) {
                long hours = timeRemaining.get()/MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR;
                long r = timeRemaining.get() - hours*MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR;
                long minutes = r/MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
                r -= minutes*MILLISECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
                long seconds = r/MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(hours);
                sb.append(":");
                if (minutes < 10) sb.append("0");
                sb.append(minutes);
                sb.append(":");
                if (seconds < 10) sb.append("0");
                sb.append(seconds);
                remainderLabel.setText(sb.toString());
            } else {
                finished.set(true);
                buttons[RESET].setText("Begin");
                buttons[PAUSE].setEnabled(false);
                remainderLabel.setText("0:00:00");
                System.out.println("Time's up!");
                player.open();
                player.repeat(3);
                player.close();
            }
        }

    }

}

public class Time implements Runnable {

    private final JFrame frame;
    private final Clock clock;
    private final Timer timer;

    // Constructor and main method omitted for brevity

    public void run() {

        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean running = true;
        while (running) {
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            clock.update(t1);
            timer.update(t1-t0);
            t0 = t1;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted Exception: " + ie.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

Note that I have made uses of classes like [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) to ensure the thread-safety of fields like `playable` and `done` so that changes by one thread are observable to other threads.

Thread-safety issues also may be arising because the instances of `clip` and `stream` that are created by one thread may not be observable by other threads. To fix this, I have made those fields `final` so that they are guaranteed to have a single reference. Java's [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class was also used to set `clip` and `stream` to a safer value than `null`.

Hope that helps. Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks.  It'll probably take me a while to digest this.  I don't have all that much more experience with concurrency than I do with sound.  My present understanding is that the program uses at least two threads.  There's the Swing Event Dispatch thread, the Runnable thread from the main program, and possibly a third thread for playing the sound--again, I'm a little shaky on how exactly the Sound API works.  Whether or not this fixes the issue, I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: You should be able to just copy and paste the code in place. Same functionality as before - no difference in logic. Let me know if it works so that your sounds play 100% of the time.

Comment: I'm afraid that the problem turned out to be logic-related rather than thread safety-related.  The program as written above prematurely disposes of the Clip and the AudioInputStream after it plays the Clip the first time so that it never works properly the second time.  Background and foreground are irrelevant.

Still, thanks for your help.  I really appreciate the introduction to the AtomicBoolean, AtomicLong, and Optional classes.

Comment: glad to hear that you solved the problem. well done!